# How can I get this string from HTML to python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

HTML

```
<td class="subject">
    <a href="bbs_update.asp?lstType=&amp;from=me&amp;idx=1119275&amp;sword=&amp;smode=&amp;page=1&amp;sel_chr_cd=&amp;sltLecCd=0&amp;MyRepleList=N&amp;searchSdt=2023-12-20&amp;searchEdt=2024-01-20&amp;sAssCd=&amp;rep_yn=&amp;que_type=&amp;std_stat=&amp;viewNo=2401201119275&amp;selSubTec=#top"> 강기분 인강민철 순서</a><br>→&nbsp;dbstjgus0707님이 답변 중 입니다.
</td>
```

I want to get the string ' dbstjgus0707님이 답변 중 입니다.' but I do not know how.

I have tried

```
def is_it_available():
    xpath_expression2 = '//a[contains(@href, "bbs_update")]'
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_expression2)
```

But this code returns the string '강기분 인강민철 순서' which is in front of `</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the text of the <a> element at the moment, the <a> tag contains the '강기분 인강민철 순서' text, so the result you got is the expected one.

To get the ' dbstjgus0707님이 답변 중 입니다.' text (which is outside of the <a> tag), you have to refer to the parent <td> element:

> //a[contains(@href, "bbs_update")]/parent::td

And then you have 2 ways:

1. Get <td> text, get <a> text, and remove the second text from the first text (either by python replace function or by string slicing by len())
2. Split the <td> text by a new line - <br> (which is converted to the \n in python world)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adjust the XPath expression.

```
def is_it_available():
    xpath_expression2 = '//td[@class="subject"]/a[contains(@href, "bbs_update")]/following-sibling::text()[1]'
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_expression2)
    text_content = element.strip()
    print(text_content)
```

This XPath expression selects the  element with the class "subject," then locates the  element with an href containing "bbs_update." Finally, it selects the first following-sibling text node, which should be the desired text '→ dbstjgus0707님이 답변 중 입니다.'.